# Excel Application not closing from MS-Project VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

The following sub is not closing the Excel Application. It remains in the task manager. It is kind a weird because I am using the same method to open and close workbooks in other modules and it works. This code is in MS-Project.

```
Sub updateModules()

    'TESTE INICIAL PARA SABER SE AS INFORMAÇÕES BÁSICAS ESTÃO INSERIDAS
    If sanity_test = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '--------------------------------//--------------------------------

    Dim xlapp As Object
    Dim xlbook As Object
    Dim sHostName As String

    ' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name
    sHostName = Environ$("username")

    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'xlapp.Visible = True
    Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(modulesVBA_loc)

    'ENCONTRAR CÓDIGO NA TABELA DO FICHEIRO MASTER
    Dim rng_modules As Range
    Dim rng_usernames As Range
    Dim username As Range
    Dim atualizado As Range
    Dim lastcol As Long


    With xlbook.Worksheets(1)
        'Última coluna
        lastcol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastcol_letter = Functions_mod.GetColumnLetter(lastcol)
    End With

    'Range com os usernames
    Set rng_usernames = xlbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E2:" & lastcol_letter & "2")
    'Encontra o username correto
    Set username = rng_usernames.Find(sHostName)

    Set rng_modules = xlbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3")  'Primeiro módulo
    Do While rng_modules.Value <> Empty
        linha = rng_modules.Row
        Set atualizado = username.Offset(linha - 2)
        If atualizado.Value = "Not Updated" Then
            With ThisProject.VBProject
                .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents("CoreTeam_mod")
                .VBComponents.Import supportDoc_loc & "Project\Próxima Actualização - Apenas PP pode modificar\VBA\Modules\CoreTeam_mod.bas"
            End With
            atualizado.Value = "Updated"
        End If
        Set rng_modules = rng_modules.Offset(1)
    Loop

    xlbook.Saved = True
    xlbook.Close

End Sub
```

**EDIT**:
Seems like the error is coming from the function that gets the column letter. I've replaced the lastcol_letter with a letter "G" and the code runs fine and closes the Excel Application properly. How should I write the function instead?

```
Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for opening excel application, you may use code something like this:

---

```
Dim xlapp as Excel.application
Set xlapp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
' your other code goes here
xlapp.quit
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `Application.Quit` at the very end that should close the instance.

Comment: I've edited the question. Found the root-cause, just needs a fix now.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `GetColumnLetter` (in MS Project), uses the Excel `Cells` object without referencing a parent object (e.g. a worksheet object). When that code runs natively in Excel, Excel implicitly uses the active sheet. However, MS Project does not do this with unqualified Excel references.

A better way to get the `Range` object you need is to do this:

```
Dim rng_usernames As Range
Dim lastcell As Range

    With xlbook.Worksheets(1)
        'Última coluna
        Set lastcell = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        'Range com os usernames
        Set rng_usernames = .Range("E2", lastcell)
    End With

End Sub
```

If Excel is still running after the macro is complete, explicitly close and set the Excel objects to Nothing at the end of your macro.

```
' close out
xlbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
xlapp.Quit 
Set xlbook = Nothing
Set xlapp = Nothing
```

Note: The [Workbook Saved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saved-property-excel) property indicates whether or not the file has been saved. Setting this to True will mean that you are not prompted to save changes when the file is closed and changes won't be saved. Your code makes changes to the file which appear something you actually  want to save. Consider using the `SaveChanges` parameter of the [Workbook Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-close-method-excel) method to explicitly save changes or not.